# How to set an option value in <md-option> of <md-select> from controller using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I've following relevant HTML code :

```
<form name="bankDetailsForm" action="save" method="POST" ng-init="getBankDetails()">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-top:0px;" flex=100> 
    <label>Transaction Type</label> 
    <md-select required ng-model="bankDetails.transactionType" ng-change="editField()"> 
      <md-option ng-repeat="type in transactionTypes" value="{{type}}">{{type}} 
      </md-option> 
    </md-select>
    <div ng-messages="bankDetailsForm.transactionType.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">Please select Transaction type</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
</form>
```

The respective controller code is as below :

```
var app = angular.module('app_name');
var isEmpty = true;

app.controller("bankDetailsController", [ "$scope", "$http", "config", "$mdToast", function($scope, $http, config, $mdToast) {
  $scope.bankDetails = {};
  $scope.transactionTypes = {
                NEFT : "NEFT",
                IMPS : "IMPS",
                WALLET : "WALLET",
               };
  $scope.getBankDetails = function() {
    $http.get(config.webServicesUrl.bankDetails, headerConfig).success(function(data) {
      if (data.body) {
        $scope.bankDetails.transactionTypes = $scope.transactionTypes.IMPS;
        isEmpty = false;
      }
    }).error(function(error) {
      console.log("Error : " + error.error);
    });
  };
}]);
```

I want the value "IMPS" to be selected in dropdown for transaction type on form load.

I tried but I could not. 
So can someone please correct my code in order to preset the value "IMPS" in a drop-down?

Thanks.

**P.S. : Please ignore ng-change="editField()" and other variables. They have been defined in configuration files and they are working fine. So please ignore them.**

Comment: Are you sure that your AJAX request through $http is success and you're getting some `body` property in the response ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo error. According to this, `ng-model="bankDetails.transactionType"`, your select is expecting `transactionType`  but you're populating `transactionTypes`.

Change the following

```
$scope.bankDetails.transactionTypes = $scope.transactionTypes.IMPS;
```

To

```
$scope.bankDetails.transactionType = $scope.transactionTypes.IMPS;
```